# How to populate a text item from Oracle table using Oracle forms (Middleware) 11gR2

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am using Oracle with Oracle Forms builder (Middleware) both 11gR2. I am creating a system for purchasing records. I have the following 2 tables.

```
(a) product (master) : prodid(PK), prodname ...... etc.
(b) purchase (detail) : prodid(FK), quantity, ...... etc.
```

My plan: All the product details will be in the product table. purchase table will be used only to input purchase information. This table can't input any new product. If any new name, that info will have to be input into product table first. This way I can reduce duplicate names.
Now I am having difficulties relating to prodname (name of the product) column in the form.

I created forms using the purchase table only. This table does not have the prodname (because I put this field in product table) column. But during data entry, they need to see the product name !
So I created text item (tabular, database - no). Then I created LOV, attached to text item, input the prodid in prodid field in the form. LOV part is fine.

I run the form. click the text item, LOV appears, select a name, click OK. product name, product id, etc. appears in their fields as it should be. LOV is working fine. Now I can only input data but having difficulties updating. I mean if I input a name (LOV) in the text item, press execute query, shows records from the database but names in the text item disappear. Since the name is not here, it's not comfortable to update.

I think LOV is not the good idea here. May be I need to use PL/SQL in a trigger somewhere.
But I could not figure it out. I searched google but no luck. Is there anyone who can give me any idea or some example code/trigger please.

Comment: edit your post, are you using oracle forms ??

Comment: Hi Exhausted, Yes. I am using Oracle with oracle Forms builder (called Middleware) both 11gR2.

Answer (score 0):

Since the product name is an non-database item, when execute query runs, the field is cleared and since no column is assigned to that field, it doesn't repopulate.

The usual way to populate this field is to have a function which returns the product name based on the id that is pressed and call the funtion in POST-QUERY trigger.

Comment: Hi Sathya, Good morning. I will try your way later today and let you know here. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hi Sathya, I used the POST-QUERY trigger and the LOV. It is working fine now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's a pretty simple task but I was having difficulties due to the lack of my experience. However, what I have done is -

1. create the text item (name : product_name) in the canvas
2. set properties for the product_name (database : No, .... etc as needed).
3. Create a block level POST-QUERY trigger and write the PL/SQL block to populate the field. For example, I wrote the following.

BEGIN
    SELECT prodname INTO :purchase.product_name
    FROM product WHERE product.prodid = :purchase.prodid ;
END ;

4. That's it and when perform execute_query in the form, it will bring the product name from another table. - Query problem is solved.
5. Now create an LOV using product table to bring the product name and product id.
6. Associate this LOV to the product_name text item. So whenever you need to input information about a purchase, just use the LOV to populate the product name field. And then input the subsequent fields as well.

This way both of my issues (query and data entry) are resolved.
I did this according to the suggestions given by Sathya and a video (6 minutes) from the youtube at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nqldnGt8KA.

Thanks to Sathya and youtube.